# How to alter a column from integer to datetime in Rails Migration ?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime, integer, migration

I have a column named `record_time` to store recorded time currently column data type is integer and the data is saved as unix timestamp now i want to find a way to convert this unix timestamp to datetime field without losing data in that column. right now i have created a migration file as follows:

```
class ChangeRecordTimeToDatetime < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    as = Audio.all.map {|a| {id: a.id, record_time: Time.at(a.record_time)}}
    Audio.all.update_all("record_time = NULL")
    change_column :audios, :record_time, :datetime
    as.map {|a| Audio.find(a[:id]).update(record_time: a[:record_time])}
  end

  def down
    as = Audio.all.map {|a| {id: a.id, record_time: a.record_time.to_i}}
    Audio.all.update_all("record_time = NULL")
    change_column :audios, :record_time, :integer
    as.map {|a| Audio.find(a[:id]).update(record_time: a[:record_time])}
  end
end
```

and this throws me an error like this

```
Mysql2::Error: Incorrect datetime value: '1493178889' for column 'record_time' at row 1: ALTER TABLE `audios` CHANGE `record_time` `record_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to convert the UNIX timestamps to DateTime objects before inserting them.  You can do so with this: `DateTime.strptime("1493178889",'%s')`

Comment: Thanks, currently i'm using `Time.at(1493178889)` is there any difference between  `DateTime.strptime("1493178889",'%s')` and `Time.at(1493178889)` just to make it more clear.

Comment: `DateTime.strptime` returns a `DateTime` object.  `Time.at` returns a `Time`.  Since your column is `DATETIME`, you'll want to stick with a Ruby `DateTime` when possible.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the UNIX timestamps to DateTime objects before inserting them.  You can do so with this: `DateTime.strptime(<timestamp>,'%s')`.

So to apply this to your question, try this:

```
  def up
    as = Audio.all.map {|a| {id: a.id, record_time: DateTime.strptime(a.record_time.to_s, '%s')}}
    remove_column :audios, :record_time
    add_column :audios, :record_time, :datetime
    as.map {|a| Audio.find(a[:id]).update(record_time: a[:record_time])}
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd skip ActiveRecord completely for this sort of thing and do it all inside the database. Some databases will let specify how to transform old values into new values while changing a column's type but I don't see how to do that with MySQL; instead, you can do it by hand:

1. Add a new column with the new data type.
2. Do a single UPDATE to copy the old values to the new column while transforming the date type. You can use MySQL's [`from_unixtime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) for this.
3. Drop the original column.
4. Rename the new column to the old name.
5. Rebuild any indexes you had on the original column.

Translating that to a migration:

```
def up
  connection.execute(%q{
    alter table audios
    add record_time_tmp datetime
  })
  connection.execute(%q{
    update audios
    set record_time_tmp = from_unixtime(record_time)
  })
  connection.execute(%q{
    alter table audios
    drop column record_time
  })
  connection.execute(%q{
    alter table audios
    change record_time_tmp record_time datetime
  })
  # Add indexes and what not...
end
```

You're well into database-specific code here so going with straight SQL seems reasonable to me. You can of course translate that to `change_column` and `update_all` calls (possibly with [`reset_column_information`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reset_column_information) calls to update the model classes) but I don't see the point: changing a column type will almost always involve database-specific code (if you want to be efficient) and migrations are meant to be temporary bridges anyway.